# Compare current value with previous and list the results if meet criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a raw table that consists of `Timestamp`, `location` and `metric`.  I would like to generate a another table where outputs only the rows where current row is lower than 40% of the previous row and the difference in terms of `percentage` between the previous record.

**Example Input**:

| Timestamp | location | metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10:00:00 | Dallas | 150 |
| 2021-10:05:00 | Dallas | 120 |
| 2021-10:10:00 | Dallas | 180 |
| 2021-10:15:00 | Dallas | 100 |
| 2021-10:20:00 | Dallas | 59 |
| 2021-10:25:00 | Dallas | 100 |

**Expected Output**:

| Timestamp | location | metric | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10:15:00 | Dallas | 100 | 56% |
| 2021-10:20:00 | Dallas | 59 | 59% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*, metric / prev_metric as ratio
from (select t.*,
             lag(metric) over (partition by location order by timestamp) as prev_metric
      from t
     ) t
where metric < 0.4 * prev_metric ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select * from (
  select *, round(100 * metric / lag(metric) over win, 0) calc
  from `project.dataset.table`
  window win as (partition by location order by timestamp)
  )
where calc < 60
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: I believe your sample data had typos in values of timestamp - last few rows all had 2021-10:15:00 value, so I assume this was a typo - thus fixed it in your question